# Thor task throws error when using gets or ARGF.readline

Tags: ruby, thor

This is Thor task:

```
  desc 'readkeys', 'Read keys'
  method_option :password, :type => :string, :desc => 'Password for the key store'
  def readkeys
    if options[:password].nil?
      puts "Enter keystore password"
      options[:password] = gets
    end

    File.open("#{Dir.home}#{File::SEPARATOR}#{ENV['USER']}.p12") do |p12|
      pkcs12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(p12.read, options[:password])
    end
  end
```

When I run the command, I get this error:

> ./mycommand:26:in `gets': No such file or directory - readkeys
>   (Errno::ENOENT)

Any ideas? The syntax seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues I see in this.   The first is that you can't actually modify the options hash from Thor. It's frozen, and you'll get a `` `[]=': can't modify frozen Thor::CoreExt::HashWithIndifferentAccess (RuntimeError) ``.

The real issue, though, is that you're working at too low a level.  What you're looking for is the `ask` method of `Thor::Actions`.   If I understand your code properly, to do what you want to do you'd do something like this:

```ruby
class Test < Thor   
  include Thor::Actions

  desc 'readkeys', 'Read keys'
  method_option :password, :type => :string, :desc => 'Password for the key store'
  def readkeys
    if options[:password].nil?
      password = ask "Enter keystore password"
    else
      password = options[:password]
    end
    File.open("#{Dir.home}#{File::SEPARATOR}#{ENV['USER']}.p12") do |p12|
      pkcs12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(p12.read, password)
    end
  end
  #...
end
```

Or, more simply,

```
class Test < Thor   
  include Thor::Actions

  desc 'readkeys', 'Read keys'
  method_option :password, :type => :string, :desc => 'Password for the key store'
  def readkeys
    password = options[:password] || ask("Enter keystore password")
    File.open("#{Dir.home}#{File::SEPARATOR}#{ENV['USER']}.p12") do |p12|
      pkcs12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(p12.read, password)
    end
  end
  #...
end
```